# How can i sort a List<string> by name?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In form1 top i have:

```
public List<string> imageList = new List<string>();
```

Then in the constructor first i tried to use only this:

```
this.imageList = Directory.GetFiles(@"e:\webbrowserimages\", "*.bmp").ToList();
```

But it didn't list the files in order as they are on the hard disk.

Now i tried this:

```
this.imageList = from file in Directory.GetFiles(@"e:\webbrowserimages\", "*.bmp")
                        orderby file descending
                        select file.ToList();
```

But I'm getting error on the select:

> Error 2   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>
>   to System.Collections.Generic.List`. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your query appropriately.  As it currently is written, you're trying to convert a list of chars (the result of calling `ToList()` on a string) to a list of strings since you're actually calling `ToList()` on the file itself instead of on the collection of files.

```
this.imageList = 
    (from file in Directory.GetFiles(@"e:\webbrowserimages\", "*.bmp")
        orderby file descending
        select file).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
file.ToList()
```

`file` is a string, which implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

Therefore, `file.ToList()` is a `List<char>`, which you're selecting as the results of your query.  This produces a collection of `List<char>`s, which is not what you want.

You need to wrap the query in parentheses to call `.ToList()` on the query itself.

Answer (score 1):

You are (almost) there. The problem you have is in the `ToList` call, which curiously works for `string`s as well, since it's an `IEnumerable<char>`.  Instead make sure you write parentheses around your Linq query before doing any operation on its result, such as `ToList`.

```
this.imageList = 
    (from file in Directory.GetFiles(@"e:\webbrowserimages\", "*.bmp")
                    orderby file descending
                    select file).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the method syntax over the sql syntax.  Call [`.OrderBy(f => f)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) before you call `.ToList()`.

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"e:\webbrowserimages\", "*.bmp").OrderBy(f => f).ToList();
```

Or, use [`.OrderByDescending()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534855(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"e:\webbrowserimages\", "*.bmp").OrderByDescending(f => f).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Directory.EnumerateFiles.

See URL: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx